# initialize complex Sparse matrix

Tags: java, apache-commons-math

I have declared a Sparse complex matrix with the apache commons-math and I have absolutely no clue on how to initialize it, besides, the documentation seems quite poor.

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.SparseFieldMatrix;

SparseFieldMatrix<Complex> Y;
```

if I try to set `Y` equal to a new instance it returns an error of `no suitable constructor`, and if I call the `Y.CreateMatrix(int, int)` it will tell that Y is Null.

So, how to initialize `Y` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the library, but looking at the [Javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/SparseFieldMatrix.html#SparseFieldMatrix%28org.apache.commons.math3.Field%29) I think this should do the trick:

```
SparseFieldMatrix Y = new SparseFieldMatrix<>(ComplexField.getInstance());
```